# Need help optimizing a triple nested Binomial CDF in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, binomial-cdf

I have to calculate a triple summation (Nested Binomial CDF), the equation is below,
[image]

It is a Binomial summation first from k = 0 to C then m = 0 to k and f = 0 to C-k, here s is a function which takes an input between 0 and 1 and gives an output between (0, 1).

I need help with finding an efficient method to execute this in python. For now I am using a triple loop which works fine but isn't efficient for large C's. The triple loop I am currently using is below,

Here 's' is essentially linear but it can take whatever shape needed. Also 'r' is taken as 0.1

```
import numpy as np
from math import comb

def s(d):
  return d * (0.99 - 0.01) + 0.01

S = 0
C = 100

for k in range(C):
  for m in range(k):
    for f in range(C-k):
      S += comb(C, k) * (((0.1)**(k))*((0.9)**(C-k))) * comb(k, m) * comb(C-k, f) * (2**(-C)) * s((f+m)/C)
```

Is there a more efficient way that I can use?

Edit: s is just a function of the following form, it takes in an input between 0 and 1 and gives output between 0.01 and 0.99 based on its shape. In the example code it is linear, but it can be exponential or whatever.

Edit2: The function 's' can't come out of the first summation, in the equation I provided it could due to a typo. It is now fixed along with inputting chrslg's suggestions.

Comment: looks like a task for `numba` package

Comment: What is `s`? (and, I know what is `comb`, but I am not supposed to guess. Please post a [mre])

Comment: Also, as written, `2**(k-C)` could be factorized and in the first level Σ. And so is `2**(-k)`. And together, they are just `2**(-C)`. That could also be factorized out the first level Σ. And so is `s(m/C)` whatever `s` is.

Comment: And once those two things factorized, the inner sum is just `2**(k-C)*s(m/C) Σ[f=0 to C-k] comb(C-k f)`. And `Σ[f=0 to C-k] comb(C-k f)` is `2**(C-k)` (it is the sum of a row of Pascal's triangle). So `2**(k-C)*s(m/C) * 2**(C-k)`. So simply `s(m/C)`. Again, whatever that is

Comment: So that is 2 nested sums, not 3. `Σ_{k=0}^C comb(C,k) rᵏ(1-r)ᶜ⁻ᵏ 2⁻ᵏ Σ_{m=0}^k comb(k,m) s(m/C)`

Comment: @chrslg Thanks for the reply, I have tried to add an MRE, hopefully that works. Also fixed a typo with 's' and included its definition. Let me know if this is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So that `s` is just an affine function. Which allows some optimization

Starting from

```py
S=0
for k in range(C):
  for m in range(k):
    for f in range(C-k):
      S += comb(C, k) * (((0.1)**(k))*((0.9)**(C-k))) * comb(k, m) * comb(C-k, f) * (2**(-C)) * s((f+m)/C)
```

Note that there is an error in this code: Σ in math notations use boundaries included (and in this kind of formula, it is quite usual to have `from 0 to n included`, which means n+1 iterations. Because when you have n socks in a drawer, and take a random number of them, then you can take 0 sock, 1 sock, 2 socks, ... up to n socks, included :D).

So, the code should read

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
  for m in range(k+1):
    for f in range(C-k+1):
      S += comb(C, k) * (((0.1)**(k))*((0.9)**(C-k))) * comb(k, m) * comb(C-k, f) * (2**(-C)) * s((f+m)/C)
```

We can get out of the loops everything that is not dependent on the index of the loop, as I mentioned in comments

```py
S=0; r=0.1
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=0
    for m in range(k+1):
        Sf=0
        for f in range(C-k+1):
            Sf += comb(C-k, f) * s((f+m)/C)
        Sm += Sf * comb(k,m) * 2**(-C)
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

Here, I just mimick the math equation rather than the code. And some operations are already factorized that way.

Sure, I can't remove directly the inner loop like this, because now you've replace `s(m/C)` which is independent from `f`, by `s((m+f)/C)` which is not.

But since `s` is affine, we can easily replace it by

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=0
    for m in range(k+1):
        Sf=0
        for f in range(C-k+1):
            Sf += comb(C-k, f) * (0.01 + 0.98*m/C + 0.98/C*f)
        Sm += Sf * comb(k,m) * 2**(-C)
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

So, one constant term, one proportional to f term

And since Σcomb(n,k) is 2ᵏ and Σk.comb(n,k) is n×2ᵏ⁻¹, we can replace this by

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=0
    for m in range(k+1):
        Sf= (0.01+0.98*m/C)*2**(C-k) + 0.98/C * (C-k)*2**(C-k-1)
        Sm += Sf * comb(k,m) * 2**(-C)
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

So here's goes one loop! Now we have 2 loops instead of 3. But it's not over yet!

Combining the `Sf=` and `Sm +=` lines

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=0
    for m in range(k+1):
        Sm += comb(k,m) * ((0.01+0.98*m/C)*2**(-k) + 0.98/C * (C-k)*2**(-k-1))
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

Note that, here again, what we are multiplying by `comb(k,m)` is made of constant terms (`0.01*2**(-k)` or `0.98/C*(C-k)*2**(-k-1)` are constant terms, as far as `m` is concerned), and proportional to `m` terms. So, using the same `Σcomb(n,k) = 2ᵏ` and `Σk.comb(n,k) = k.2ᵏ⁻¹` formulas, we can rewrite again

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=(0.01*2**(-k) + 0.98/C * (C-k)*2**(-k-1))*2**k + (0.98/C*2**(-k))*k*2**(k-1)
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

And here's go the second loop! Just one left. Not over yet!

Which can be simplified as

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=0.01 + 0.49/C*(C-k) + (0.49/C)*k
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

Or even

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    Sm=0.01 + 0.49 - 0.49/C*k + (0.49/C)*k 
    S += Sm*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

So, Sm=0.5 obviously

```py
S=0
for k in range(C+1):
    S += 0.5*comb(C,k) * r**k * (1-r)**(C-k)
```

But `Σ comb(n,k) aᵏbⁿ⁻ᵏ` is the well known development of (a+b)ⁿ.
So that is 0.5×(r + (1-r))ᶜ = 0.5×1ᶜ = 0.5

Hence the ultimate simplification of your code (sorry, can't do better than that!)

```py
S=0.5
```

And you can easily check that, once the boundaries problems corrected, your code also returns 0.5 whatever the parameters (C and r) are.

## Some numpy trick

Since this is supposed to be a numpy question, not a math simplification question, here is how you can accelerate this kind of computation with numpy.

Suppose you are trying to compute the inner loop

```py
for f in range(C-k+1):
     Sf += comb(C-k, f) * s((f+m)/C)
```

(the more interesting one. The one because of which I wanted to know `s`, and particularly if it was vectorizable. My initial plan was to give the kind of answer I am giving now, if `s` was vectorizable, that is if `s` can work with both scalars and arrays as parameters. But I had to change my plan when I saw that `s` was even affine, which is even better. But, well, let's suppose that `s` is more complicated, for example contains `sin`, `log` or even just some higher order polynomials that make my formal computation impossible)

If, we could compute, at once, a vector of `C-k+1` values, using vectorized functions (again, functions that works on whole arrays, if asked to), then we could skip the `for` loop, and sum that with numpy's `sum` method. It is still a `for` loop in reality. But a hidden one, and, more importantly, one that occurs inside numpy's optimized C code, node in our slow pure python.

We can start with a vector of values for `f`
`f=np.arange(C-k+1.0)`. Note the `1.0`, lazy way to ensure it is float

Good news is your `s` (and probably all `s` you could think of, even with the `sin`, `log` or higher degree polynomials I've mentioned) is vecorized. So we can easily compute a vector of `s((f+m)/C)`.
That is simply by literally doing that: if `f` is a vector, then so is `(f+m)/C` and so is `s((f+m)/C)` since `s` is vectorized.

So, the harder part is the comb part.

With numpy you can do it with a `cumprod`

```py
f=np.arange(C-k+1.0)
np.seterr(divide='ignore') # Just because the 1st term I am about to compute is 1/0
combRatio=((C-k-f)/f) # That is also a vector, since f is
combRatio[0]=1 # neutral cumprod
mycomb=combRatio.cumprod() #  All ΠcombRatio aka comb(f,C-k)
```

So, now we have a vector of `comb(f,C-k)` and a vector of `s((f+m)/C)`. To have a vector of all terms, we just need to multiply both

```py
f=np.arange(C-k+1.0)
np.seterr(divide='ignore') # Just because the 1st term I am about to compute is 1/0
combRatio=((C-k-f)/f) # That is also a vector, since f is
combRatio[0]=1 # neutral cumprod
mycomb=combRatio.cumprod() #  All ΠcombRatio aka comb(f,C-k)
terms = mycomb * s((f+m)/C)

# And the Σ result is simply
terms.sum()
```

Note that if you are willing to use scipy, it is even simpler, since scipy contains a vectorized `comb` function

```py
f=np.arange(C-k+1.0)
Sf=(scipy.specials.comb(C-k,f) * s((f+m)/C)).sum()
```

This times, no math tricks from me. I simplified nothing. This is just coding tricks that made the loop disappear. It is still there (inside scipy's `comb`, numpy's `+`, `-`, `*` and `.sum()`). There are even 5 of them now (non-nested, and way more than 5 times faster than a pure python loop)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since s can take different shapes (could be exp, sigmoid or whatever) the first part wouldn't work for my case. Linear was only an example. But the second part really helps, s is indeed vectorizable so this will save me a lot of time and I also learnt something new!

Answer (score 0):

You could compute `comb(C, k) * (((0.1)**(k))*((0.9)**(C-k)))` only once per `k`
and `comb(k, m)` only once per `m` like this :

```
for k in range(C):
    step_1 = comb(C, k) * (((0.1) ** (k)) * ((0.9) ** (C - k)))
    for m in range(k):
        step_2 = step_1 * comb(k, m)
        for f in range(C - k):
            S += step_2 * comb(C - k, f) * (2 ** (-C)) * s((f + m) / C)
```